# Hamburger menu not toggling/clickable

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, hamburger-menu

So I have loaded the bootstrap.js as well as the jQuery.js file in external resources. I wonder why I am not getting the hamburger menu to toggle/dropdown on click. 
Here is the fiddle link for the same

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/rkhambekar/coeqovhw/3/`
```

Comment: You haven't attached jQuery which is necessary for all Bootstrap's JavaScript components. [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/coeqovhw/4/)

Comment: just put `jquery.js` before `bootstrap.js`  [jsfiddle-exampie](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/coeqovhw/5/)

Comment: I am actually new to using jsfiddle and that's why made the silly mistake. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Just drag the reference of the jquery.min.js from bottom to the top  before bootstrap.min.js in the External Resources in the same fiddle itself and you will get it working.

Comment: thanks :) Silly mistake as just started using jsfiddle